# Keras dimension LSTM net 3 dim expected

Tags: python, input, keras, lstm, dimension

I've a problem with the input dimensions & shape of a LSTM sequential network . I'm searching the right way to reshape and adapt this input_merged (?, 1, 2400, 60) to LSTM
The input has been successfully concatenated, but the new dimension is not accepted from LSTM net input.

***Program***

```
inp1 = Input(features_set3.shape)
inp2 = Input(features_set4.shape)
print("  shapeINP1 ")
print(inp1.shape)
print("  shapeINP2 ")
print(inp2.shape)

input_merged = Concatenate(axis=2)([inp1, inp2])

print(input_merged.shape)
print("  OK  ")

lstm = LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_merged.shape)(input_merged)

model = Sequential()  

model.add(LSTM)
```

***Logs with dimension error and the input shape***

> b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
>   42
>   Using TensorFlow backend.
>
> features_set
>   (1200, 60)
>
> features_set3
>   (1, 1200, 60)
>    DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by MinMaxScaler.
>    warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)
>
> features_set2
>
> (1200, 60)
>
> features_set4
>
> (1, 1200, 60)
>
> shapeINP1
>
> (?, 1, 1200, 60)
>
> shapeINP2
>
> (?, 1, 1200, 60)
>
> (?, 1, 2400, 60)
>
> OK
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   prog10-t12.py", line 84, in module
>      lstm = LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_merged.shape)(input_merged)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 532, in call
>    return super(RNN, self). call (inputs, kwargs)
>   File "base_layer.py", line 414, in call
>    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
>    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 311, in assert_input_compatibility
>      str(K.ndim(x)))
>
> **ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4**

Answer (score 0):

you should reshape you inputs tensor first:

```
inp1 = keras.layers.Reshape((1200, 60))(inp1)
inp2 = keras.layers.Reshape((1200, 60))(inp2)
```

or

```
input_merged = keras.layers.Reshape((2400, 60))(input_merged)
```

this will change the shape of `input_merged` to `(None, 2400, 60)` and thus acceptable by LSTM layer

Comment: I get an input error about the Reshape command for inp2        > inp2 = keras.layers.Reshape(1200, 60)(inp2)
> TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: > features_set 
> (1200, 60) 
> features_set3 
> (1, 1200, 60) 
> DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by MinMaxScaler.
  > warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)
> features_set2 
> (1200, 60) 
> features_set4 
> (1, 1200, 60) 
 > shapeINP1 
> (?, 1, 1200, 60) 
>  shapeINP2 
> (?, 1, 1200, 60) 
>  shapeINP2-Reshaped 
 > Traceback (most recent call last):
   > prog10-t13.py", line 82, in module
    > inp2 = keras.layers.Reshape(1200, 60)(inp2)
> TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: pardon, I forgot brackets, try out `keras.layers.Reshape((1200, 60))(inp2)`

Comment: Hi, this solution is causing a missalignement with the Concatenation previously solved , Maybe the inp2 reshape needs also a Concatenate change
ValueError: A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 1, 1200, 60), (None, 1200, 60)]

Comment: yeah, I misunderstood provided output. you can reshape both `inp1` and `inp2` or reshape only `input_merged`